# Package that downloads data from the internet during installation

Tags: r, packaging

Is anyone aware of a package that downloads a dataset from the internet during the installation process and then prepares and saves it so that it is available when loading the package using `library(packageName)`? Are there any drawbacks in this approach (besides the obvious one that package installation will fail if the data source is unavailable or the data format has changed)?

**EDIT**: Some background. The data is three tab-separated files in a ZIP archive, owned by federal statistics and generally freely accessible. I have R code which downloads, extracts and prepares the data, in the end three data frames are created which could be saved in `.RData` format.

I am thinking about creating two packages: A "data" package that provides the data, and a "code" package that operates on it.

Comment: Why do you not want to include the data with the package?

Comment: @AnandaMahto: The data changes regularly, and I don't want to be submitting a new version of the package every time this happens.

Comment: I think downloading data from the Internet without asking the user is considered to be rude. I'd rather include a function `updateData()` or `installData()`, so that the user can decide by himself, if or when he wants to do that. And then include some version number for the dataset.

Comment: What is the format of the data currently? An .RData file? CSV? HTML? Also, I agree with @DanielFischer that it would probably be best to leave some sort of user decision in the process. Do the functions in your package depend on the data?

Comment: @krlmlr Sorry for the long comment thread here. Are you creating the data? Would it be possible for you to save it as RData files instead? Or do you have another function that downloads the zip file, extracts its contents, and then makes the data available?

Comment: Another workaround could be to host your package on Github and to use `install_github` from the `devtools` package to install it. That way you can just push your updated dataset to your repository and your users can get it in a convenient way. You can even submit to CRAN from time to time.

Comment: @juba, I think your comment here is the most appropriate answer, but does `update.packages()` work with packages installed via `install_github()` or is there a way to make it work? Otherwise, the data might still be out of date....

Comment: @AnandaMahto No, you're right, I don't think `update.packages()` would work. You would to have to rerun an `install_github` manually to update the package...

Comment: @juba, ... at which point, we're back to re-dowloading. There's probably a clever way to figure out the version that's installed and compare it to the version online before deciding whether to download it or not. Perhaps parsing the package description file would suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this mockup before, while you were posting your edit. I presume it would work, but not tested. I've commented it so you can see what you would need to change. The idea here is to check to see if an expected object is available in the current working environment. If it is not, check to see that the file that the data can be found in is in the current working directory. If that is not found, prompt the user to download the file, then proceed from there.

```
myFunction <- function(this, that, dataset) {

  # We're giving the user a chance to specify the dataset.
  #   Maybe they have already downloaded it and saved it.
  if (is.null(dataset)) {

    # Check to see if the object is already in the workspace.
    # If it is not, check to see whether the .RData file that
    #   contains the object is in the current working directory.
    if (!exists("OBJECTNAME", where = 1)) {
      if (isTRUE(list.files(
        pattern = "^DATAFILE.RData$") == "DATAFILE.RData")) {
        load("DATAFILE.RData")

        # If neither of those are successful, prompt the user
        #   to download the dataset.
      } else {
        ans = readline(
          "DATAFILE.RData dataset not found in working directory.
          OBJECTNAME object not found in workspace. \n
          Download and load the dataset now? (y/n) ")
        if (ans != "y")
          return(invisible())

        # I usually use RCurl in case the URL is https
        require(RCurl)
        baseURL = c("http://some/base/url/")

        # Here, we actually download the data
        temp = getBinaryURL(paste0(baseURL, "DATAFILE.RData"))

        # Here we load the data
        load(rawConnection(temp), envir=.GlobalEnv)
        message("OBJECTNAME data downloaded from \n",
                paste0(baseURL, "DATAFILE.RData \n"), 
                "and added to your workspace\n\n")
        rm(temp, baseURL)
      }
    }
    dataset <- OBJECTNAME
  }
  TEMP <- dataset
  ## Other fun stuff with TEMP, this, and that.
}
```

---

### Two packages, hosted at Github

Here's another approach, building on the comments between @juba and I. The basic concept is to have, as you describe, one package for the codes and one for the data. This function would be part of the package that contains your code. It will:

1. Check to see if the data package is installed
2. Check to see if the version of the data package you have installed matches the version at Github, which we are going to assume is the most up to date version.

When it fails any of the checks, it asks the user if they want to update their installation of the package. In this case, for demonstration, I've linked to one of my packages in progress at Github. This should give you an idea of what you need to substitute to get it to work with your own package once you've hosted it there.

```
CheckVersionFirst <- function() {
  # Check to see if installed
  if (!"StataDCTutils" %in% installed.packages()[, 1]) {
    Checks <- "Failed"
  } else {
    # Compare version numbers
    require(RCurl)
    temp <- getURL("https://raw.github.com/mrdwab/StataDCTutils/master/DESCRIPTION")
    CurrentVersion <- gsub("^\\s|\\s$", "", 
                           gsub(".*Version:(.*)\\nDate.*", "\\1", temp))
    if (packageVersion("StataDCTutils") == CurrentVersion) {
      Checks <- "Passed"
    }
    if (packageVersion("StataDCTutils") < CurrentVersion) {
      Checks <- "Failed"
    }
  }

  switch(
    Checks,
    Passed = { message("Everything looks OK! Proceeding!") },
    Failed = {
      ans = readline(
        "'StataDCTutils is either outdated or not installed. Update now? (y/n) ")
      if (ans != "y")
        return(invisible())
      require(devtools)
      install_github("StataDCTutils", "mrdwab")
    })
# Some cool things you want to do after you are sure the data is there
}
```

Try it out with `CheckVersionFirst()`.

> *Note*: This would succeed only if you religiously remember to update your version number in your description file every time you push a new version of the data to Github!

So, to clarify/recap/expand, the basic idea would be to:

- Periodically push the updated version of your ***data*** package to Github, being sure to change the version number of the ***data*** package in its `DESCRIPTION` file when you do so.
- Integrate this `CheckVersionFirst()` function as an `.onLoad` event in your ***code*** package. (Obviously modify the function to match your account and package name).
- Change the commented line that reads `# Some cool things you want to do after you are sure the data is there` to reflect the cool things you actually want to do, which would probably start with `library(YOURDATAPACKAGE)` to load the data....

Comment: I like this approach, this is similar to how `tikzDevice` caches font metrics. Is there any "default" storage which is always writable by the user?

Comment: Thanks for your input. It seems to me that the standard approach, using `data()` to load a dataset, allows custom R scripts to be executed. Exactly what I need. Now the only open question remains to find a suitable location for the cache. I have opened a new question for that: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14874909/946850

Comment: @krlmlr, I've added a little bit of clarification. But, perhaps I don't quite understand the problem you're trying to tackle.

Comment: Thank you. Your approach is valid in many scenarios, but I don't want to push the data to Github because I am not the owner of the data -- even if the data is publicly available. Also, I don't want to be updating packages when the data is updated. I believe that I am legally on the safe side if the package downloads the data from the data owner, and it reduces maintenance burden a lot. I think I have found the answer to my question, I'm accepting your answer for your valuable input.

Answer (score 1):

This method may not be efficient, but a good workaround. If you are making a package that needs regularly updated data, first make a package which has that data. It does not need any functions, but I like the concept of a setter (which you might not need in this case) & getter.

Then when you make your package, have the 'data'-package as a dependency. This way, whenever someone installs your package, he/she will always have the latest data.

On your part,  you'll just have to swap out the data in your 'data' package, and upload it to the repo you want.

If you don't know how to build a package, check `?packages.skeleton` and `R CMD CHECK`, `R CMD BUILD`

Comment: What do you mean by setter and getter?

Comment: it is a concept from object oriented programming where any external function cannot access data/variables belonging to a class (in our case, our data-package). Instead, we write functions to return the values of the variables/data. This way the data stays protected from outside influence.

Comment: I am aware of the concept. Would it be possible to alter the data of an installed package (using the *setter* you mentioned)?

Comment: It could. but only locally- so wouldn't work for a distribution to multiple people. But if only you're gonna use it, it might just!

Comment: I see -- I have opened a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14874909/946850