# Is there a persistent location that is always writable which can be used as data cache by a package?

Tags: r, package

Is there a predefined location where an R package could store cached data? The data should persist across sessions. I was thinking about creating a subdirectory of `${R_LIBS_USER}/package_name`, but I'm not sure if this is portable and if this is "allowed" if my package is installed systemwide.

The idea is the following: Create an R script `mydata.R` in the `data` subdirectory of the package which would be executed by calling `data(mydata)` (according to the documentation of `data()`). This script would load the data from the internet and cache it, if it hasn't been cached before. (If the data has been cached already, the cache will be used.) In addition, a function will be provided to invalidate the cache and/or to check if a newer version of the data is available online.

This is from the documentation of `data()`:

> Currently, four formats of data files are supported:
>
> 1. files ending ‘.R’ or ‘.r’ are source()d in, with the R working directory changed temporarily to the directory containing the respective file. (data ensures that the utils package is attached, in case it had been run via utils::data.)
> 2. ...

Indeed, creating a file `fortytwo.R` in the `data` subdirectory of a package with the following contents:

```
fortytwo = data.frame(answer=42)
```

and then executing `data(fortytwo)` creates a data frame variable `fortytwo`. Now the question is: Where would `fortytwo.R` cache the data if it were difficult to compute?

**EDIT**: I am thinking about creating two packages: A "data" package that provides the data, and a "code" package that operates on it. The question concerns the "data" package: Where can it store files in a per-user storage so that it is persistent across R sessions and is accessible from different R projects?

Related: [Package that downloads data from the internet during installation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14871818/946850).

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://github.com/hadley/rappdirs - it's a port of AppDirs, which is a python library that tries to find the right directories in a OS-specific way.

Comment: Just trying to clarify: DO you mean where can data be stored after it has been processed by an R script? In other words, is your question really about the data from the data package, or the data that are generated as output from any processing that has taken place? It *sounds* like the latter.

Comment: @hadley: Is there a chance that this is going to appear on CRAN any time soon? If there is no R-specific way to do this (like putting it into a subdir of `${R_USER_LIBS}), I'll gladly use your package.

Comment: @AnandaMahto: I imagine the following workflow: 1. The code package loads the data package, and calls `data(mydata)`. 2. `data/mydata.R` in the data package looks in the cache if the data has been downloaded already. If not, it downloads the data, reshapes it and puts it into the cache. Either way, the reshaped data is loaded into the current R environment. 3. The code package uses the data from the data package to do fancy stuff.

Comment: @krlmlr working on other projects at the moment, so not in the near future. But if it passes R CMD check and if you try it on a few platforms, it's probably not a big deal to submit

Comment: @hadley: The package passes `R CMD check --as-cran`. I will get back to you when I have some test results for other platforms.

Comment: I would suggest providing the data itself in the data package, and provide a way to download (and cache) the data on demand in the code package. That way, users who want to explicitly download the data permanently can do so. (I realise that data size could be an issue here.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no absolutely defined location for package-specific persistent caching in R. However, the [R.cache package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.cache/index.html) provides an interface for creating and managing cached data. It looks like it could be useful for your scenario.

When users load R.cache (`library(R.cache)`), they get the following prompt:

```
The R.cache package needs to create a directory that will hold cache files.
It is convenient to use one in the user's home directory, because it remains
also after restarting R. Do you wish to create the '~/.Rcache/' directory? If
not, a temporary directory (/tmp/RtmpqdUcbP/.Rcache) that is specific to this
R session will be used. [Y/n]:
```

They can then choose to create the cache directory in their home directory, which is presumably persistent, or to create a session-specific directory. If you make your data package depend on R.cache, you could check for the existence of the cached object(s) in its `.onLoad()` hook function and download the data if it isn't there. Alternatively, you could do this in the way suggested in your own question.

Answer (score -3):

Have you looked at in-memory databases? H2 & Redis have bindings in R via RH2 & rredis- both allow you to share the data across r sessions- till the creating session is alive. in order to have it persisting across non-concurrent sessions, you need to write your data to the disk (assuming you can't re-create it on the fly- that would defeat the purpose of this question), and I believe the data package would be a good option. That way, you could add an update function that initializes everytime you load either package (i.e. if the code package has the right dependencies)

An example is RWeka & RWekaJars packages. Look them up on CRAN, and it should be fairly easy to understand how they work.

Comment: I can write the data to disk in R's native format. I just need to find a place *where* I can put them so that other R sessions will find it there.

Comment: Like I said, I use in-memory databases. H2 & redis serve me well.